# Save body text on csv file | Python 3

Tags: python, csv, web, screen-scraping

I am trying to create a database with several articles for Text mining purposes. 
I am extracting the body via web scraping and then save the body of these articles on a csv file. However, I couldn't manage to save all the body texts. 
The code that I came up with saves only the text the last URL (article) while if I print what I am scraping (and what I am supposed to save) I obtain the body of all the articles.

I just included some of the URL from the list (which contains a larger number of URLs) just to give you an idea:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv

r=["http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/12/world/europe/germany-arrest-syrian-refugee.html",
"http://www.nytimes.com/2013/06/16/magazine/the-effort-to-stop-the-    attack.html",
"http://www.nytimes.com/2016/10/06/world/europe/police-brussels-knife-terrorism.html",
"http://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/23/world/europe/france-terrorist-attacks.html",
"http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2016/09/09/us/document-Review-of-the-San-Bernardino-Terrorist-Shooting.html",
]

for url in r:
    t= requests.get(url)
    t.encoding = "ISO-8859-1"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(t.content, 'lxml')
    text = soup.find_all(("p",{"class": "story-body-text story-content"}))
    print(text)
with open('newdb30.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try declaring variable such as `all_text = ""` before the for loop and adding `text` to `all_text` by `all_text += text + "\n"` at the end of the for loop (the `\n` creates a new line).

Then, in the last row, instead of writing `text`, you write `all_text`.

Comment: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list. So I edit it in str(text)+ "\r\n". And it seems to be working now the output is something like this: d a t a - t o t a l - c o u n t = " 6 5 5 2 " > M r . | | T h é v e n e t | | i s | | n o t | | s u r e | | w h e n | | — | | o r | | e v e n | | i f |  Any tips on how to make it more readable?

Comment: Did you do `all_text = []` or `all_text = ""` before the for loop? It should be second.

Comment: I used the second one as suggested all_text = "". By adding str(text) I solve the error but I get an output hard to read.

Comment: I see. You can add only an element of a list by doing e.g. `all_text += text[0] + "\n"` if you want to to write only the first element. You can also add a separator line between each page text by doing `all_text += text[0] + "\n---\n"`